# Saving Command History/Outputs to a file - GRASS

Tags: grass-gis

Is there any way to save the commands typed and the outputs obtained in terminal under GRASS GIS to a text file? I have read that GRASS saves history for each mapset but I have no much idea about how to obtain that.

Although there is "Save Output" in "Command Console" in GRASS GIS Layer Manager, many times I have faced a situation when the saved output has only one line!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three command history logs are available within each mapset.

Inside the **hist** directory, you will find command logs for each raster layer.

Within the sub-directories **vector**, you will find the command logs for each vector layer.

There is also **.bash_history** file in the main mapset directory for all commands logs you used during a GRASS session.

All of them are simple text files.

Comment: They were really useful inputs. But I ran `r.covar` and the output obtained is not found on **.bash_history**. Is there any other directory where they get stored or do I have to export the output exclusively to a file.

Comment: .bash_history is usually save when you exit/finish a GRASS session.

Comment: I checked after exiting as well. But only `exit` is shown after my `r.covar` inputs.

Comment: Do you mean to save the r.covar output or the command itself?  To save the command output, try `r.covar map=mapx > file.txt`

Comment: Alright, thank you. Its mainly to save the output but at times I have to look back into commands typed in previous sessions as well.

Comment: .bash_history is not created in my customized version of i.aicorr(grass gis 6.4.4). is there a way to write it to text file for seeing the error log  manually.